# Use Spring Batch to write in different Data Sources

Tags: spring-batch

For a project I need to process items from one table and generate 3 different items for 3 different tables, all 3 in a second data source different from the one of the first item. The implementation is done with Spring Batch over Oracle DB. I think this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25850944/spring-batch-read-once-and-write-twice) has something similar to what I need, but in there it is writing at the end only one different item.

To ilustrate the situation:

```
DataSource 1                               DataSource 2
------------                        ------------------------------

   Table A                          Table B     Table C    Table D
```

The reader should read one item from table A. In the processor, using the information from the item in A, 3 new items will be created of type B, C and D. In addition, the item from table A will be updated.

The writer should be able to write at the same time all 4 items. My first implementation is using a JpaItemWriter to update the item A, but I don't know how the processor could give the other 3 items to the writer in order to save all at the same time.

Can a processor return several items from different types? Would I need to create 4 steps, each one writing one of the items? And in this case, would that be error safe (If there is an error writing D, then A, B, and C would be rollback)?

Thanks in advance for your support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is really two questions.  Let's look at each individually:

**Can an `ItemProcessor` return multiple items**
An ItemProcessor can only return one item at a time for each item that is passed in.  Because of this, in your specific scenario, you'll need your `ItemProcessor` to return a wrapper object that wraps items A, B, C, and D.

**How can I write different types in the same step**
Spring Batch relies heavily on composition in it's programming model.  Since your `ItemProcessor` will be returning a wrapper object, you'll end up writing an `ItemWriter` that unwraps items A, B, C, and D and delegates the writing of each to the apropriate writer.  So in the final solution, you'll end up with 5 `ItemWriter`s: one for each item type and one that wraps all of those.  Take a look at our `CompositeItemWriter` as an example here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/support/CompositeItemWriter.java