# CompositeItemWriter with Wrapper

Tags: spring, spring-batch

1. reader -> injest a class named Person
2. processor -> injest Person, and returns a wrapper object, that has 3 fields, all of them are of type Person (1. inputPerson, 2. outputPerson, 3. output)
3. writer -> injest this wrapper and should write first two fields in one file, and the third one in a second file as xml.

That is the code, that I have written for this problem:

```
  @Bean
  public CompositeItemWriter<Wrapper> compositeItemWriter(){
    CompositeItemWriter writer = new CompositeItemWriter();
    writer.setDelegates(Arrays.asList(firstTwoWriters(), thirdWriter));
    return writer;
  }

@Bean
public StaxEventItemWriter<Wrapper> firstTwoWriters() {
     StaxEventItemWriter<Wrapper> xmlFileWriter = new StaxEventItemWriter<>();
    xmlFileWriter.setRootTagName("something");
    String outputName = applicationArguments.getOptionValues("output").get(0);
    FileSystemResource outputResource = new FileSystemResource(outputName);
    xmlFileWriter.setResource(outputResource);
    Jaxb2Marshaller personMarshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    scoringMapMarshaller.setClassesToBeBound(Person.class);
    xmlFileWriter.setMarshaller(personMarshaller );
}
```

The problem is, that i cannot choose which field (inputPerson, outputPerson or output) should be used by this writer(which field should be converted to xml). 
Any ideas, how can I do this? (if possible with an example)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836312/use-spring-batch-to-write-in-different-data-sources  
I have read everything here and it looks similar to my problem, but I do not understand how should I write Unwrapper, cause the problem is the same: I do not know how to choose which field should be used by the writer.

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve without referring to Spring Batch? What is the input/output of your job?